# Kafka Consumer message handling

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming

I have three consumers polling for data continously. Consumers consume data, do some validation and persist the message offset and few of message details in DB before sending that consumed message to other application. Now how can I handle my messages if my DB is down? what are possible solutions to resume message processing without loosing data once db is up and running?